# Using .ix loses headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How come when I use:

```
dfa=df1["10_day_mean"].ix["2015":"2015"]
```

The dataframe dfa has no header?

dfa:

```
Date
2015-01-10    2.000000
2015-01-20    3.000000
```

df1:

```
           10day_mean  Attenuation  Channel1  Channel2  Channel3  Channel4  \
Date                                                                          
2004-02-27       3.025       2.8640       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Is there a way to change the header of the dfa because when I plot it out my legend is the 10_day_mean and I wish to relable it as "Daily mean of every 10 days"

Thanks guys

I tried

```
dfa=dfa.rename(columns={0:"rename"})
```

and
    dfa=dfa.rename(columns={"10day_mean":"rename"})

But then it says none

Comment: Post raw data and code that reproduces this, also is this really correct code: `dfa=df1[10_day_mean].ix["2015":"2015"]` shouldn't the column name be in quotes? `dfa=df1['10_day_mean'].ix["2015":"2015"]`?

Comment: It is, I just wrote it wrong -sorry

Comment: I think you are confusing that `dfa=df1["10_day_mean"].ix["2015":"2015"]` gives you a `Series` so there is no column if you did `dfa=df1[["10_day_mean"]].ix["2015":"2015"]` then you'd get a single column dataframe

Comment: Try: `df1.ix["2015":"2015", ["10_day_mean"]]` if you only want to keep the "10_day_mean" column and retain the DataFrame structure. Use `df1.ix["2015":"2015"]` if you want to keep all the columns.

Comment: Cheers,  it was the second [] so what is the difference exactly? 

And Olaf: thanks thats useful to know :)

Comment: Sorry are you asking about `dfa=df1[["10_day_mean"]].ix["2015":"2015"]`? This returns a df because you passed a list of strings, albeit a list containing a single column this is semantically the same as if you did `df[['col1','col2']]`

Comment: Oh that makers a lot of sense! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion here is that when you do this:

```
dfa=df1["10_day_mean"].ix["2015":"2015"]
```

this returns a `Series` which only has a single column so the output doesn't show the column name above the column, it'll show it at the bottom in the summary info as `name`.

To get the output you desired you can use double subscripting to force a dataframe with a single column to be returned:

```
dfa=df1[["10_day_mean"]].ix["2015":"2015"]
```

Example:

```
In [90]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[90]:
          a         b         c
0 -1.002036 -1.703049  2.123096
1  0.497920  1.556211 -1.807895
2  0.400020 -0.703138  1.452735
3 -0.296604 -0.227155 -0.311047
4 -0.314948 -0.654925 -0.434458

In [91]:
df['a'].iloc[2:4]

Out[91]:
2    0.400020
3   -0.296604
Name: a, dtype: float64

In [92]:
df[['a']].iloc[2:4]

Out[92]:
          a
2  0.400020
3 -0.296604
```